# An error occurred while attempting to process /view/ajax: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: ajax, drupal, view

Getting this error on a Drupal view exposed filter when i change the value on the select list. Tried every combination of jquery and jquery UI. Traced the call stack to misc/ajax.js:

```
Error
    at alert (<anonymous>:4:15)
    at Drupal.ajax.eventResponse (ajax.js?v=7.36:262)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (ajax.js?v=7.36:178)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:5)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:5)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:4)
    at $.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:4)
    at $.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:5)
```

Comment: You are not providing enough information for us to help. Ajax should not be firing when a select element is changed. by default it only fires when the exposed form is submitted. Do you have any module or custom code that manipulates the exposed form?

Comment: the view is ajax enabled. so when you select an option from the exposed filter select list, ajax is called to populate the block with the new criteria.

Comment: Like I said, as far as I know, even with ajax enabled, an exposed form would submit when a submit button is pressed,. If it is submitting on a select change event, then it is not the default behavior and something is altering it.  Add more detail to your question, as it is now it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: you can hide the submit and auto-submit in the exposed form settings: http://i.imgur.com/a5KrACS.png

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry. Still can't help any more without more information. Is what you posted above what prints out in the js console? Do you not see a js alert popup?

Comment: i should have mentioned :) Any advice/ideas on how to deal with this error?

Comment: "Still can't help any more without more information." How long are you going to keep on saying that? I gave you the call stack which i traced. The original error is in an alert and i did some browser hacks to find the origin of the alert... that's all the information i have, can't trace it any further than i have.

Comment: lol, nice attitude, I wont bother any more

Comment: yeah thanks, but I don't need your help

Comment: Try turning off the view ajax?

Comment: i figured it out - it was some of my application code changing the array prototype. creating a "compare" array prototype basically breaks the ajax/views functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out - it was some of my application code changing the array prototype. creating a "compare" array prototype basically breaks the ajax/views functionality.